# How to use "across" after be

Tags: word-usage, writing

I am not so sure how to use "across" in this situation.

(1) Can I say

> The bridge is across a river.

Can "across" directly fellow after "be"?

(2) If the usage in (1) is right. Can I use "across" in this case?[image]

> Black bridge (black stickin the bild) is across the senond grass (green rectangle, there are four regions of grass).

If I say it like above, whether others misunderstand that the black bridge is only across region 2 and no others. But actually, it is also across region 3 and 4. If it is wrong, how can I describe that the black bridge is "across" region 2?

Comment: A bridge _crosses_ a river or _goes, was built across_ a river. _Across_ the river is on the other side of the river.

Comment: So, across can not follow directly after _is_?

Comment: No. As I said, _across the river_ means on the other side of the river. A bridge is by necessity on both sides. You walk/drive over a bridge to get across the river. The bridge crosses the river so you can get across.

Answer (score 1):

A better sentence might be as follows: 'The bridge crosses a river.' or 'The bridge spans a river.'

NOTE: I substituted "spans" in place of "crosses" because it's more precise. "Crosses" has a connotation of 'action'...think of it from a visual perspective of seeing a flying bridge going from one side of a river to the other; whereas "spans" seems more sedentary. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two definitions for [across](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/across):

> - across (adverb, preposition) = **from one side to the other** of something with clear limits, such as an area of land, a road, or a river
> - across (preposition) = **on the opposite side** of

Of course, the two meanings are quite different, and different people might different things from the same sentence.

So the following is correct (using the "from one side to the other"):

> The bridge is **across** a river.

An alternative way ti say the same thing, removing ambiguity, is:

> The bridge is **over** a river.

---

However, using the "on the other side" definition, the sentence:

> The bridge is **across** a river.

Means that AFTER you cross the river (method is unspecified), you will find a bridge. Possibly, it is a bridge over a highway, over a railways track, or anything else. It can be quite close, or quite far - also unspecified.

> The XY bridge is not in this part of the city. The bridge is across the river.

(assume a big city, split in "half" by a river)